# Setting max_connections using PHP or .htaccess?

Tags: php, sql

I'm experiencing a max_user_connections error for the first time :

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1226): User 'xxx' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30)
```

I know many threads are related to this error but they're either too old for me to reply or the solutions lack details for my case.
I cam to this attempt based on different answers but doesn't change a thing :

```
$connexion = mysqli_connect($hote, $utilisateur, $mPasse, $nombase) 
or die("Error");
$set_max = mysqli_query($connexion, "set global max_connections = 2000");
```

What does this error mean ? 30 visitors are surfing the website or there are more than 30 SQL requests at the same time (it's not supposed to) ?
What's best to increase max number ? PHP or a .htaccess file ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change this limit at the PHP or webserver level. It's a setting in the database server, and that's where you'd have to increase it if you wanted to.

The cause is going to depend on your code and the traffic you receive. If your code opens a new connection for every query (instead of reusing a connection for all the queries in one request), 31 queries on one page *would* put you over the limit.

High traffic could also cause it, especially if your PHP scripts take a long time to run.

Comment: Thanks. It could be the cause. My connection happens on my unique index.php page where I use include() to call for dynamical content. SO basically, everytime a new page is loaded. Maybe I should rethink that.
But can I change or ignore the limit as an emergency to give me time to repair it without blocking the website ?

Comment: @Greg If it's shared hosting, probably not. If it's a database server you set up yourself, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a shared one. Is that a daily or simultaneous limit ? The website is down since a few hours, there shouldn't be any request active at the moment.

Comment: @Greg It would be simultaneous connections. If you're receiving regular traffic you may be staying regularly over the limit. If you can get into the database, `SHOW PROCESSLIST` should show you the currently-running queries.

Comment: No, phpMyAdmin is locked aswell. There shouldn't be any connexion active as I "commented" the connexion line on my php files.

Comment: You should consult your host, then, unfortunately.

Comment: On a friday night, that's unfrtunate for sure :) Thanks a lot for trying to clarify and resolve my problem !

Answer (score 1):

You can increase it for a specific user with a MySQL statement:

`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user_name'@'user_host' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 50;`

You can also add this line to the configuration file `my.cnf`:

`max_user_connections=50`

However, that will set the limit for *all* users.

This could be happening for a few reasons, the most common ones involving when the Web/App server is creating unexpectedly large numbers of connections due to a miss-configuration or some script/application leaking connections or creating too many connections in error.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't think I can access my.cnf. The MySQL statement has to be set in PhpMyAdmin ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case `max_connections` has nothing to do and can't be controlled at the webserver level (so no PHP or htaccess directives will help)

What the error means is that your database username has too many open connections on the database server. This may happen for many reasons:

> 1. too much traffic

This may be a happy problem. Too much concurrency could cause this problem on its own and the simplest solution would be to get a new database server with better specs to handle the load and then increase the max_connections limit for your db user.
However, as happy-path as this may seem, I'd usually believe this is not the culprit as a well built website-database interaction could handle hundreds (or more) concurrent users without ever getting closer to the max_connections limit (currently I'm seeing 300 concurrent users on a small website I manage and the open connections on the database is steady at 5)

> 2. Connections are being left open

Probably not the case, but do ensure that you close DB connections on your code after using them. PHP usually handles this on its own, but it's good practice to terminate the connections yourself anyway

> 3. Opening multiple connections to the same database on each pageview

One common error is to establish a database connection for every query you need to run instead of establishing only one connection for every query related to a pageview. If your site is highly dynamic and needs a lot of DB data, you could easily be running 20-30 or more queries on each hit. If you're opening a new connection for each of those, you may hit your max_connections limit quite fast (particularly if the queries take long to run... long being, well, over a couple hundred miliseconds)

My advice here would be to open the DB connection once at the beggining of your code, close it at the very end and use that link to run all queries in between. Besides not hitting your max_connections limit that easily, you'll see a performance increase by removin the overhead of actually connecting to the database server multiple times

Comment: Thanks for all the details. As far as I know, I have 1 connexion on each page with up to 3 requests by page loaded. Is that a daily limit ? I mean, with the website down since a few hours, I doubt there are any request active at the moment.
My emergency will be to unlock the website. Is that possible ?

Comment: the limit isn't daily... it's a simultaneous connections. So if at any moment you have more than 30 open connections for the same db user, further connection attempts will fail until one or more slots are released. To buy some time, you may increase the connection limit for your db user, but your focus should then be determining why are connections being kept open (if you're using persisting connections, that could be the reason as PHP won't terminate those on its own). If you're running slow queries that would be another cause, but it wouldn't explain the site remaining down with no traffic

Answer (score 0):

**False alert !**
I finally manage to join my host assistant and they informed me that it was an internal issue. Most customers are impacted and by checking my stats they could assure me I'm usually far from the limit. Sorry, this auto-answer won't help much users. Well, if you get this error, try contacting your assistance first.
Thanks for those who take time to give me intels and advices anyway.